# Data per weeks previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sort data by weeks for previous month and I look for code which is usable automatic without manually writing the dates.

Instead of this:

```
SELECT
wadat_ist AS 'frame'
,CASE
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-01' THEN 'MA1'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN '2019-09-02' AND '2019-09-08' THEN 'MA2'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN '2019-09-09' AND '2019-09-15' THEN 'MA3'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN '2019-09-16' AND '2019-09-22' THEN 'MA4'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN '2019-09-23' AND '2019-09-30' THEN 'MA5'
END AS 'Activity'
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
wadat_ist AS 'frame'
,CASE
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (SELECT (Convert (DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)))))) AND  (SELECT DateAdd (wk, 0, (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, +0.99999)))) THEN 'MA1'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (SELECT DateAdd (wk, -4, (SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0))))) AND (SELECT DateAdd (wk, 1, (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)))) THEN 'MA2'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (SELECT DateAdd (wk, -3, (SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0))))) AND (SELECT DateAdd (wk, 2, (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)))) THEN 'MA3'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (SELECT DateAdd (wk, -2, (SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0))))) AND (SELECT DateAdd (wk, 3, (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)))) THEN 'MA4'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (SELECT DateAdd (wk, -1, (SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0))))) AND (SELECT DateAdd (wk, 4, (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)))) THEN 'MA5'
END AS 'Activity'
```

But the results are quite different. Values from first week are in the second week, values from second week are in the third and so on .. .all weeks are shifted somehow... Furthmore first week (MA1) is marked as NULL but his values should go to last week (MA5).

Plus I find this one, but it counts few weeks into one, but as the time goes, it matches to the rigt week, so maybe on the first of november will be fine, but I rather need something that will show data anytime in month.

```
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)) AND (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 5, getdate()) - 5, 6)) THEN 'MA1'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 4, getdate()) - 4, 0)) AND (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 4, getdate()) - 4, 6)) THEN 'MA2'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 3, getdate()) - 3, 0)) AND (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 3, getdate()) - 3, 6)) THEN 'MA3'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 2, getdate()) - 2, 0)) AND (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 2, getdate()) - 2, 6)) THEN 'MA4'
WHEN wadat_ist BETWEEN (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 1, getdate()) - 1, 0)) AND (SELECT EOMONTH(getdate(),-1)) THEN 'MA5'
```

Using T-SQL

Comment: Could you provide us some sample data and expected results please (as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements)? That'll really help us help you.

Comment: Looks like, as well, you're talking about conditional aggregation. using lots of subqueries is a sure fire way to slow the query down, so we can help you with that too.

Comment: My feeling is that you should be relying on something like `DATEPART()`, using `week` as the part.

Comment: Define "week". Sunday to Sunday? Monday to Monday? And what is the first week of year?

Comment: In other word you should explain on what basis you want to makr 'MA1' ,'MA2' etc.

Comment: Why would you be using `SELECT` with no `FROM` clause in the "subqueries"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ofcourse I have a FROM clause, I just didnt write it up. I am just a newbie to StackoverFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below (partial) query, comments are inline:

```
-- set monday as first day of week
set datefirst 1;

-- after checking, that 1 of september is 35th week of year, you can do the following:
select case when datepart(week, wadat_ist) = 35 then 'MA1'
            when datepart(week, wadat_ist) = 36 then 'MA2'
            when datepart(week, wadat_ist) = 37 then 'MA3'
            when datepart(week, wadat_ist) = 38 then 'MA4'
            when datepart(week, wadat_ist) = 39 then 'MA5'
       end as 'Activity'
```

or shorter

```
select case datepart(week, wadat_ist) 
            when 35 then 'MA1'
            when 36 then 'MA2'
            when 37 then 'MA3'
            when 38 then 'MA4'
            when 39 then 'MA5'
       end as 'Activity'
```

Comment: the first one with SET worked with the right values, but still, all weeks are shifted and first week is still marked as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As a one of the solutions you can create TimeTable in your database or temp table with your range of time period and then generate column WeekOfMonth:
1. create table at least with these columns(date, year, month, week, quarter : use `DATEPART`)
2. generate your column:

```
WeekOfMonth = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [year], [month] ORDER BY [week])
```

If you create a good time table it will be useful for future tasks.

Comment: This is good advice, it's the famous Calendar Table. The OP just has to spend a little time creating it and making sure that it has the correct week data, then just join by date. Be careful with weeks though, they are a little convoluted to compute.

Comment: @EzLo, the computation is not enormously difficult. It is the definition of the concept which is tricky - true weeks (always whole, always running between fixed weekdays such as Mon-Sun) are incommensurate with months, so a *month-week* must permit partial weeks, and the question is then whether there is (a) alignment with the (true) weekly cycle and part-weeks potentially at each end, or (b) whether it is simply a division of month-days into groups of seven, starting on the 1st of the month, ending (usually) with a partial final week, and with no alignment to the true weekly cycle.